# colorpicker can't set value to property

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, color-picker

Hi I'm trying to add colorpicker for my page. I downloaded this and I can show colorpicker. We are using .net core.

[The code](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/XfFVgt) I choose "colorpicker-picker-longlist"

my cshtml

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label asp-for="UsColor" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
```

//this way it wasnt worked for me but when I changed "name" to "id" it works

#ac725e
#d06b64
#f83a22
#fa573c
#ff7537
#ffad46
#42d692
#16a765
#7bd148
#b3dc6c
#fbe983
#fad165
#92e1c0
#9fe1e7
#9fc6e7
#4986e7
#9a9cff
#b99aff
#c2c2c2
#cabdbf
#cca6ac
#f691b2
#cd74e6
#a47ae2



It shows the color when i put color attribute in get controller. It's okay but when I change color and submit the changed values does not comes to post controller.

in post

```
usViewModel.UsColor; comes null
```

Comment: What does this have to do with .Net core?

Comment: I gotta set selected color to model property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,asp-for cannot be recognized in div,and model cannot be modified with selected value in view directly.If you want to change the value of input,you can do like this:

View:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="UsColor" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Color</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input asp-for="UsColor"/>
        <div class="picker" id="picker1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#picker1").colorPick({
            'initialColor': '#8e44ad',
            'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
            'onColorSelected': function () {
                console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color)
                this.element.css({ 'backgroundColor': this.color, 'color': this.color });
                $("#UsColor").val(this.color);
                return this.color;
            }
        });
```

result:
[image]

If you want to pass value to action without form,you can use ajax:

js:

```
$("#picker1").colorPick({
            'initialColor': '#8e44ad',
            'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
            'onColorSelected': function () {
                console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color)
                this.element.css({ 'backgroundColor': this.color, 'color': this.color });
               $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                   url: '@Url.Action("ChangeColor", "Test")',
                   data: { "color": this.color }
                 }).done(function (data) {

                });
                return this.color;
            }
        });
```

TestController:

```
public IActionResult ChangeColor(string color) {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer,it will hlep but I gotta post with all form data

Comment: Can you share more about your view model?You mean you want to post all the model data to action?

Comment: Thank you for your gifs and your support. It helped me. I finally make it with new color picker. I change name to id and it works.

Comment: You're welcome.Can you mark it as answer?

Answer (score -2):

make sure to import js and css files, use jquery 1.12.4 (as provided in demo file) , but it is old version. Sure you must use a newer version.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/colorPick.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/colorPick.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .picker {
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 36px;
            height: 36px;
            cursor: pointer;
            -webkit-transition: all linear .2s;
            -moz-transition: all linear .2s;
            -ms-transition: all linear .2s;
            -o-transition: all linear .2s;
            transition: all linear .2s;
            border: thin solid #eee;
        }
        .picker:hover {
            transform: scale(1.1);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="picker" id="picker1"></div>
<div class="picker" id="picker2"></div>
<script>
    $("#picker1").colorPick({
        'initialColor' : '#8e44ad',
        'palette': ["#1abc9c", "#16a085", "#2ecc71", "#27ae60", "#3498db", "#2980b9", "#9b59b6", "#8e44ad", "#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
        'onColorSelected': function() {
            console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color)
            this.element.css({'backgroundColor': this.color, 'color': this.color});
        }
    });

    $("#picker2").colorPick({
        'initialColor' : '#34495e',
        'palette': ["#34495e", "#2c3e50", "#f1c40f", "#f39c12", "#e67e22", "#d35400", "#e74c3c", "#c0392b", "#ecf0f1"],
        'onColorSelected': function() {
            console.log("The user has selected the color: " + this.color)
            this.element.css({'backgroundColor': this.color, 'color': this.color});
        }
    });
</script>
  
</body>
```

files can be downloaded from the link you have provided

Comment: jquery 1.12 was made in 2016.... The latest version is 3.5

Comment: I included but this code does not answer, its identical. I just gotta set selected color to model propeyer , " UsColor"

Comment: jquery is used in the downloaded files 
https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Flat-HTML5-Palette-Color-Picker-For-jQuery-colorPick-js.html
but in demo is using 3.1.1

Comment: I understand you but what I just need is set selected color to property, and thic doe upside is not doing it

Comment: You can get the parent (form-group) of picker:
let pickerpare = $("#picker1").parent(".form-group");
then inside oncolorfunction change it's color
pickerpare.css({'backgroundColor': this.color, 'color': this.color});

Comment: :) I can get this selected color vlaue but it not effects to asp-for field

Comment: I have created a single html page with all the scripts, it is working (the color is changing after selection).
the selection adds a style attribute to div element that has id=picker1, aps-for is tag helper should be used with input element.
if you want to send value from form I suggest that you add an input with type hidden and asp-for attr, then set its value to this color.
hope this will help

Comment: Hi i found another solution with dropdown color slect but it still not working